# mysql LIKE returning only one row when three match

Tags: php, mysql

When I query my database with the following in my file, search.php, it only returns the first result it comes across.

```
$qry = "SELECT business_id FROM business WHERE zip like '%91326%'";

$rs = mysql_query($qry);
$rec = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
echo $session->showContents($rec);
```

showContents is just a utility function...

```
function showContents($array)
{
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($array);
        echo "</pre>";
}
```

showContents returned this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [business_id] => 3
)
```

The crazy thing is, when I put the same query in sqlbuddy it gives me:

```
business_id
3
5
6
```

I am at a loss

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) fetches only a single row.  You want to use it several times to build an array with the entire result set:

```
$rec = array();

while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) !== FALSE) {
    $rec[] = $row;
}
```

If you just want the ID's you want to select the ID:

```
$rec = array();

while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) !== FALSE) {
    $rec[] = $row[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$qry = "SELECT business_id FROM business WHERE zip like '%91326%'";
$rs = mysql_query($qry);
while ($rec = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    echo $session->showContents($rec);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `mysql_fetch_array` only fetches a single row from the result set.

Typically you use it like this (from [the manual](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array)):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
}
```